# how to minimize or disable codec transcoding from freeswitch to asterisk?

Tags: asterisk, codec, freeswitch

i want to pass call from freeswitch to asterisk without transcoding, freeswitch(Version 1.4.6  32bit) and asterisk-11.7.0 are installed at same machine, in freeswitch call codec description is write_codec=L16 write_rate=16000 write_bit_rate=256000, in freeswitch i have tried

```
<param name="disable-transcoding" value="true"/>
```

then asterisk displays

> Found RTP audio format 98
>
> Found RTP audio format 13
>
> Found audio description format L16 for ID 98
>
> chan_sip.c:10556 process_sdp: No compatible codecs, not accepting this offer!

I think freeswitch internally using `L16` and asterisk is using `SLIN`,

How to minimize or disable codec transcoding in both freeswitch and asterisk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also can use g722 or any other narow band uncompressed codecs.

All uncompressed codecs requires very low cpu to do transcode into any other uncompressed(much less then handling of stream)

Comment: Dear @arheops  thank u for answer, i am runing asterisk 11.7, both freeswitch and asterisk are installed at same machine and communicating via 127.0.0.1, kindly suggest a codec for both